# how windows cuts a file, change path or transfer full data

Tags: java, windows, file

I wonder how windows cuts a file into another location ? does it change the file path only? or transfer the whole file data?

can you write a program in java to cut files in a fast way ?

Comment: Are you asking how to cut|paste works?

Comment: If it's still in the same disk partition, it will only update the directory entries, it will not move any data.

Comment: yes how cut/paste works in windows

Comment: I think Cut|paste does a smart rename using the SHFileOperation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use cut and paste with files, Windows will *move* the file if it's on the same device (disk partition, etc.). That is, it will just update the file system's record, it won't have to copy the file data.

You can use [`File#renameTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) in Java to do the same thing, provided the OS can do so with the source and destination.

If you cut and paste a file across devices, Windows has to copy the file data (of course), and then delete the old file. `File#renameTo` won't do that; the rename will fail (it'll return `false`) and you have to respond to that by doing the file copy (and then removal of the old file) yourself.

Comment: yes that's why if you move large size file from one location to another location in same partition then it takes little time
but if you move large size file from one location to another location in different partition then it takes more time because system must have to copy data from one partition to another partition
correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @DarshanPatel: That's what I said above: *"If you cut and paste a file across devices, Windows has to copy the file data (of course), and then delete the old file."*